# How to check if JSON node is a short or not

Tags: java, json, jackson, short, fasterxml

I have a json node and I am suppose to check if it an array or not. If the node is an Array then each value should be a short value. Hence for each value I am checking if it is a number using isNumber() API. However I want to know if this number is a Short or not. How to do that?
Code:

```
JsonNode attrNode = rootNode.path("product_id_anyof");
if ((attrNode.getNodeType() == JsonNodeType.ARRAY) { ///this part is working.
    for (final JsonNode node : attrNode) {
        if (!node.isShort()) { ///returns false even if the number is a short.
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

expected: if short is given it should return true but it always gives false.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON` `number` by default is read as `int`, try to check whether given `number` value is `short` manually:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeType;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(onlyShortsArray(mapper.readTree("[1,2,3,4]")));
        System.out.println(onlyShortsArray(mapper.readTree("[1,2,3, 33333]")));
        System.out.println(onlyShortsArray(mapper.readTree("[1,2,3, \"a\"]")));
    }

    private static boolean onlyShortsArray(JsonNode attrNode) {
        if (attrNode.getNodeType() == JsonNodeType.ARRAY) {
            for (final JsonNode node : attrNode) {
                if (node.isInt()) {
                    try {
                        Short.valueOf(node.asText());
                        continue;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```